# c# Mapping lists to ILookup<int,tenant>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Based on the following  classes.

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<TenantUser> TenantUsers { get; set; }
    }


    public class TenantUsers
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int TenantId { get; set; }
        public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tenant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TenantUser> TenantUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to generate a linq query that will return an `Lookup<int,Tenant>()`
The `int` being the userId from TenantUsers.

My attempt so far:

```
var userIds = new int[] {1, 2,3,5};
var tenantUsers = new List<TenantsUsers>();

var tenants = 
tenantUsers
.Where(m => userIds.Contains(m.UserId))
.ToLookup(x=>x.UserId);
```

Above is how far I got. This returns `ILookup<int,TenantUsers>` I am looking for `ILookup<int,Tenant>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select `Tenant` from the result like this.

```
var userIds = new int[] {1, 2,3,5};
var tenantUsers = new List<TenantsUsers>();

var tenants = 
tenantUsers
.Where(m => userIds.Contains(m.UserId))
.ToLookup(x => x.UserId, y => y.Tenant);
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XG6tlt)